# Javascript Regex prototype

Tags: javascript, regex, prototype

Why is Chrome's console displaying `/(?:)/` for the RegExp's prototype?

```
console.log(RegExp.prototype);
console.log(/a/.__proto__);
```

Is this something implementation specific? IE is displaying `//`.

This is just a question out of curiousity. I tried to view all prototype methods of regular expressions in javascript, when I encountered this. Of course I found other ways of looking up those methods, but this keeps me wondering why this result is displayed.

I hope this question has not been asked before - did not find anything on Stackoverflow. Thanks!

Comment: `(?:)` i a empty group that doesn't give a match: `"hello".replace(/(?:hello)/, "$1"); // "$1"` While `"hello".replace(/(hello)/, "$1"); // "hello"`

Comment: @NULL: `(?:)` is a non-capture group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Relevant section from spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6)

> The RegExp prototype object is itself a regular expression object; its
>   [[Class]] is "RegExp". The initial values of the RegExp prototype
>   object’s data properties (15.10.7) are set as if the object was
>   created by the expression new RegExp() where RegExp is that standard
>   built-in constructor with that name.

[Then we go to `new RegExp()` section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1), which is same as calling it with the empty string. So now we have empty regex object as the prototype.

The string representation [is defined to be](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.4):

> Return the String value formed by concatenating the Strings "/", the
>   String value of the source property of this RegExp object, and "/";
>   plus "g" if the global property is true, "i" if the ignoreCase
>   property is true, and "m" if the multiline property is true.
>
> NOTE The returned String has the form of a RegularExpressionLiteral
>   that evaluates to another RegExp object with the same behaviour as
>   this object.

It ultimately comes down to `.source` property (explained in the [new RegExp section](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1)), which is implementation defined as long as it behaves the same when used as regex:

> Let S be a String in the form of a Pattern equivalent to P, in which
>   certain characters are escaped as described below. S may or may not be
>   identical to P or pattern; however, the internal procedure that would
>   result from evaluating S as a Pattern must behave identically to the
>   internal procedure given by the constructed object's [[Match]]
>   internal property.

Since `new RegExp("(?:)")` and `new RegExp("")` behave identically, both chrome and IE are following the spec correctly. The spec even mentions this specific situation as an example:

> If P is the empty String, this specification can be met by letting S
>   be "(?:)"

Chrome's way can be considered "better" since it appears to work as regexp literal as well: `/(?:)/` is a valid regex literal whereas `//` starts a one-line comment.

Comment: BTW, there is a string in spec saying "If P is the empty String, this specification *can be* met by letting S be "(?:)"."

Comment: Thanks, just the perfect answer. I will have a look at the spec, thanks for the link - I will already accept your answer as you pointed exactly out what i was looking for.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that in _JavaScript_ syntax, if you want to type a _RegExp_ literal, `//` won't work because it will become a comment, whereas `/(?:)/` will work, despite them both meaning the same thing in terms of _RegExp_.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks, I added it :P Paul S. yea I added that as well thanks

Comment: However, `RegExp.prototype instanceof RegExp` is `false`.

Comment: @plalx `instanceof` is defined as *Is [[rhs]].prototype in the prototype chain of [[lhs]]?* and the answer is no since the spec says that the [[prototype]] of `RegExp.prototype` is *is the standard built-in Object prototype object*

Comment: @Esailija, Yeah I know exactly why, but that means the spec is slightly contradictory. `RegExp.prototype` is not an instance of `RegExp`, it's an object that have the same interface as an instance of `RegExp` on which the `RegExp` constructor was applied. Obviously, it's pointless to specify that it has the same interface since it's the object defining the inteface for `RegExp`.